# Azure VM pre-made storage account: prerequisites

Tags: azure

In Azure, when creating a VM, you can choose to "Use an automatically generated storage account".
Which, generates a geo-replicated storage account.

Can I create a zone replicated storage account and use that? I have tried, but it does not show up in the list.

What are the prerequisites for a storage account to be usable for the VM's?

Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only restriction is that you can't choose a ZRS account to be used by VMs because `VMs are essentially stored as Page blobs in blob storage and ZRS account only support block blobs`. From the storage team blog here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/01/introducing-zone-redundant-storage.aspx:

> As you can see, these options provide a continuum of durability and
>   availability options. ZRS fits between LRS and GRS in terms of
>   durability and price. ZRS stores 3 replicas of your data across 2 to 3
>   facilities. It is designed to keep all 3 replicas within in a single
>   region, but may span across two regions. **ZRS currently only supports
>   block blobs**. ZRS allows customers to store blob at a higher durability
>   than a single facility can provide with LRS. ZRS accounts do not have
>   metrics or logging capability enabled at this time.